# Embedded music player not working in opera and mozilla browser

Tags: mozilla, opera, media-player

The media player embedded code work only in IE.How I can do it able to work on opera ,mozilla and other browser.I am using this below code.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<OBJECT ID="Player" height="0" width="0"
  CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
</OBJECT>
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" NAME="BtnPlay" VALUE="Play" OnClick="StartMeUp()">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" NAME="BtnStop" VALUE="Stop" OnClick="ShutMeDown()">
<SCRIPT>
<!--

function StartMeUp ()
{
    Player.URL = "laure.wma";
}

function ShutMeDown ()
{
    Player.controls.stop();
}

-->
</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Windows Media Player ActiveX control, which only works in IE.

It can work in FireFox if the [Windows Media Player Firefox Plugin](http://port25.technet.com/pages/windows-media-player-firefox-plugin-download.aspx) is installed on the user's computer.

For best results, you should probably use Flash.